# Game maker pause menu clicking

Tags: android, game-maker

I have an obj pause controller. It used to work when using up/down arrow then enter to click something in the pause menu. BUT how exactly do I get it use left mouse clicks (touch screen) instead of the enter key. I have this code as my enter key.

```
if (interest == "resume")
{
    instance_destroy();
}
else if (interest == "levels")
{
    room_goto(worlds);  
}
else if (interest == "main_menu")
{    
    room_goto(main);
}
```

And this in my draw gui

```
draw_sprite(background, 0, 640, 360);
draw_sprite(spr_border, 0, 640, 360);

if (interest == "resume")
{
    draw_sprite(spr_resume, 0, 640, 360 - 100);
    draw_sprite(spr_levels, 0, 640, 360);
    draw_sprite(spr_main_menu, 0, 640, 360 + 100);
}
else if (interest == "levels")
{
    draw_sprite(spr_resume, 0, 640, 360 - 100);
    draw_sprite(spr_levels, 0, 640, 360);
    draw_sprite(spr_main_menu, 0, 640, 360 + 100);
}
else if (interest == "main_menu")
{
    draw_sprite(spr_resume, 0, 640, 360 - 100);
    draw_sprite(spr_levels, 0, 640, 360);
    draw_sprite(spr_main_menu, 0, 640, 360 + 100);
}
```

I tried using this in my step event to get the clicking (touching) to work but its not working at all (nothing activates when touching or clicking). Is this even right?

```
if(device_mouse_check_button_released(0, mb_left)){
    if (device_mouse_x(0) > 640 && device_mouse_x(0) < 640 + sprite_get_width(spr_resume)
   && device_mouse_y(0) > 260 && device_mouse_y(0) < 260 + sprite_get_height(spr_resume)){
      //RESUME IS TOUCHED
   }
 }  
   if(device_mouse_check_button_released(0, mb_left)){
       if (device_mouse_x(0) > 640 && device_mouse_x(0) < 640 + sprite_get_width(spr_levels)
    && device_mouse_y(0) > 260 && device_mouse_y(0) < 260 + sprite_get_height(spr_levels)){

  }
}

if(device_mouse_check_button_released(0, mb_left)){
    if (device_mouse_x(0) > 640 && device_mouse_x(0) < 640 + sprite_get_width(spr_main_menu)
    && device_mouse_y(0) > 260 && device_mouse_y(0) < 260 + sprite_get_height(spr_main_menu)){
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I see a number of problems with your code that you will all need to address for anything to work:

1. Your interest variable is checked for changes, but nowhere is it actually changed (I would expect it to be changed in your step event script, but it doesn't do anything).
2. Your draw gui script draws exactly the same thing for three different values of interest. There's no visible change whatsoever.
3. You jump to a new room and display the selected interest at the same time (when releasing the selection), which means you'll never see the selection. You should a) draw the selected interest on press and b) jump to the room on release.

Furthermore, keep in mind that more than one finger could touch the screen simultaneously -you're only checking for the first touch where there can be 5.

A last suggestion in the GameMaker context is to use objects to check for finger press and release events (the mouse events translate as finger events on touch screens) rather than scanning screen areas for presses. It's what makes GameMaker so much easier to use as it automatically checks the instance's sprite area for collisions, a built-in behavior.